# Is it safe to start an activity, which returns data using setResult(intent, code), with startActivity()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I start an activity with `startActivityForResult()` at few places and with `startActivity()` at few other places. My new activity sets result using `setResult()` method. Will I be getting any error and is it a good practice to do this?

Comment: Hey Flat Eric , i dont think it is an invalid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. It is no problem. If you don't need the result in the calling Activity, then you don't need to launch the Activity with `startActivityForResult()`. This is analogue to the following in Java:

```
// A method that does something on Monday, and returns a boolean result indicating
//    whether it did something or not
boolean doSomethingOnMonday() {
    if (monday) {
        // Do something here and tell the caller that we did it
        ...
        return true;
    }
    // Don't do anything. Tell the caller that we didn't do anything
    return false;
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
boolean monday = doSomethingOnMonday();
```

or like this:

```
if (doSomethingOnMonday()) {
    ...
}
```

or like this:

```
// Do something on Monday, but I don't care if we did it or not, so ignore the
//    method's return value
doSomethingOnMonday();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. Appreciate :)